# Stopping of Visual Studio debugging sometimes crashes IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm debugging WebAPI C# application by sending requests in Swagger on Windows 10. After a few launches and stoppings (I didn't find any regularity) Visual Studio debugger crashes Local IIS Server **after debugging stopped**, and it takes a lot of time to restart it, many minutes. What's the problem may be? Thanks.

**UPD:** So, I didn't send logs to MS. The problem has disappeared after I reinstalled Windows.

Comment: Right click your app->Properties->Web, please disable the "Enable Edit and Continue", clean and rebuild the solution, debug it again. Please also check that whether you could find more detailed output messages or Event logs in your side if still no help.

Comment: This option is not allowed

Comment: You could disable it before you start debugging or stop debugging, if you couldn't disable it, one possible reason is that your app is in debugging time.

Comment: No, that option is completely disabled and not allowed in project. I can't change code during debugging.

Comment: not debug your app, if you run it using "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)", does it work normally? If just have this issue in debugging, please close all third party processes or tools in your windows, and then disable the symbols server and  IntelliTrace under TOOLS->Options. At least, we have to make sure that it is not the performance issue, of course, you could also debug the same app in other VS machine and narrow down this issue.

Comment: Would you please share us the latest information about this issue? If still no help, I suggest you collect the crash dump files.

Comment: I has not had time to research the problem deeper, but it is still appears. I had tried to search for logs but not found suitable. What exactly logs describe that error?

Comment: Generally we could visit the event log to get information, but for the crashed issue, I suggest you collect the crashed dump file, and report it to the connect report team:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx, they will help you debug the dump file and get much more useful information to analyze and troubleshoot this issue.